# Rounding off to two decimal places

Tags: python, pandas

```
corr_matrix = data.corr()
corr_matrix.sort_values('SalePrice', ascending = False, inplace = True)

print(corr_matrix.SalePrice)
```

How do i alter my code so that I can round off the answers to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Using integers is probably the way to go here

Comment: `corr_matrix = corr_matrix.round(2)`

Comment: Is it for calculations or representation?

Answer (score 4):

simply use `.round()`

```
corr_matrix = data.corr()
corr_matrix = corr_matrix.round(2) #<-- as I posted in the comments
corr_matrix.sort_values('SalePrice', ascending = False, inplace = True)

print(corr_matrix.SalePrice)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

> pandas.DataFrame.round

Official documentation about the function: [pandas.DataFrame.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)

Comment: Because you don't actually know what OP is trying to do based on the question...